# Allowing single touch events to pass through UIScrollView

Tags: uiscrollview, uikit, touchesmoved

I have a view `drawingView` for drawing where I use touchesBegan,Moved,End to add curves to a subview `renderingView` that renders them.  I also wanted to support zooming and panning on this same screen so I added a `UIScrollView` as a subview of `drawingView` and returned `renderingView` in my scrollView delegate's `viewForZooming` method.

Now, all the zooming/panning works.  `renderingView` zooms in, still lays out the bezier curves, I can pan around the zoomed in rendering, etc..  However, my initial feature of actually drawing into `renderingView` by using the touches* methods of `drawingView` is no longer functioning, as the scrollview is a subview and is consuming touch events.

I am willing to set the scrollview's panning to a minimum of 2-finger gestures, therefore the zooming/pinching and the panning will be 2-finger gestures leaving room for the `canvasView` to handle the single finger touches* events to add path information.

Now, I found a way (though it seems like a hack) of setting the scrollview's pan gesture to a minimum of two finger touches by iterating through its gestures and checking when its the pan gesture.  However, setting this to a minimum of two-finger touches, doesn't allow my `canvasView` to begin getting touch events.  How can I do that?

## TL;DR

A `UIScrollView` subview is eating the touchesBegan/Moved/Ended events of its superview.  How can I get around this is I'm willing to limit the scrollView's events to two finger gestures and let single finger gestures be handled by the super view??

Answer (score 0):

Consider using gesture recognizers, it will make your life easier. Also use a single view for getting touch events, and pass touch data to other objects.

Use UIPinchRecognizer for zooming and panning, UIPanRecognizer for actual drawing. You can set UIPanRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches to 1.

You may want to check Apple's site for implementation details.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizer

Comment: the problem with gestures is that they actually have a bit of a delay before they "engage".  leading to a laggy drawing experience.  secondly, scroll view appears to have 3 gestures, and its difficult to set them all to 2 minimum touches such that any 1 touch events propagate through the scroll view cleanly.